# update the data in laravel and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to update my data in angularJS(frontend) and laravel(backend).
But even I got an data from id, but I always make a new data.
I thought it cause my laravel code's fault, but not sure.

AngularJS service

```
 app.factory('Assets', function($resource) {


    return $resource('/api/assets/:assetId',{assetId:'@id'},{
      update: {
           method: 'PUT' // this method issues a PUT request
              }
  }); 
});
```

Controller (for data list)

```
app.controller('fixedAssetListCtrl',['$scope','$location','$rootScope','Assets', function($scope, $location, $rootScope,Assets){
$scope.assets = Assets.query();

$scope.goEdit = function(id){

    Assets.query({assetId:id}.edit);
    $location.path('/editFixedAsset').search({assetId:id});

}


}]);
```

Controller (for edit)

```
 app.controller('fixedAssetEditCtrl',['$scope','$location','$rootScope','Assets', 
function($scope, $location, $rootScope, Assets){

    var edit_id=$location.path('/editFixedAsset').search();


    var assetId=parseInt(edit_id.assetId);
    //window.alert($rootScope.assetId.ID);


    $scope.editassets = Assets.query({assetId});// getting data 
    // console.log($scope.editassets);

    $scope.asset = {}; 

    $scope.updateFixedAsset =function(asset){
        var faData ={
                            detailAssetCode:$scope.detailAssetCode,
                            detailDescription:$scope.detailDescription,
                            detailParchaseDate:$scope.detailParchaseDate,
                            detailSoldDate:$scope.detailSoldDate


                        }  //end of faData


    Assets.update({assetId},asset);

}


}]);
```

Laravel Routes

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/api'), function () {
Route::resource('assets', 'AssetController');

});
```

Controller

```
public function show($id){
    $assets = FAModel::find($id);


        $response[] = [
            'detailAssetCode' => $assets->AssetCode,
            'detailDescription' => $assets->Description,               
            'detailPurchaseDate' => $assets->PurchaseDate,
            'detailoldDate' =>$assets->SoldDate,

        ];





    return Response::json($response, 200);
}

public function update($id){
$FAModelObj = new FAModel;
    $fixedAssetData = FAModel::find($id);
        $FAModelObj->AssetCode = Input::json('detailAssetCode');
        $FAModelObj->Description = Input::json('detailDescription');//need to be JSON object??
        $FAModelObj->PurchaseDate =  Input::json('detailPurchaseDate');
        $FAModelObj->SoldDate =  Input::json('detailSoldDate');


        $FAModelObj->push();




    return Response::json(array('success'=>true));

}
```

Can you find the problem??
How can I change to update the data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new instance to save data instead of existing one. That's why new row is created in database. Your code should be like that.

```
public function update($id){

    $fixedAssetData = FAModel::find($id);
    $fixedAssetData->AssetCode = Input::json('detailAssetCode');
    $fixedAssetData->Description = Input::json('detailDescription');//need to be JSON object??
    $fixedAssetData->PurchaseDate =  Input::json('detailPurchaseDate');
    $fixedAssetData->SoldDate =  Input::json('detailSoldDate');
    $fixedAssetData->push();

    return Response::json(array('success'=>true));
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Yes! It works now! I put 
     $FAModelObj = new FAModel; 
because I got an error...(sorry I forget what it is now, I will find and comment later.)
But this is helpful. Thanks @Arkar Ang